# Why do normal modes not exchange energy between each other?

Tags: energy, eigenvalue, normal-modes

I've been looking around for an answer to this and have had trouble learning about why this is.

Does it have to do with the fact that the modes are eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Normal modes are eigenmodes of the system, and thus are decoupled from one another. Assume the following differential equation

$$\ddot{\boldsymbol{x}}=A\boldsymbol{x}$$

where $A$ is a symmetric matrix. It is always possible to define new coordinates $\boldsymbol{x}^{\prime}$ where the matrix is diagonal and thus the above equation is

$$\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x}_{1}\\\vdots\\\ddot{x}_{n}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_{1}x_{1}\\\vdots\\\lambda_{n}x_{n}\end{pmatrix}$$

This is **mathematically equivalent** to $n$ **different** systems that you've just decided to stuck together. Take a SHO that sits on Mars and a ball floating without gravity in outer space. You can say that

$$\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x}_{1}\\\ddot{x}_{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\omega^{2}x_{1}\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Those two systems certainly don't exchange energy, and there is no reason to think otherwise about normal modes.